# How to turn a template function in a template class to a function pointer

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to turn a concrete factory into a template factory class. The following is what I wrote; I am working with g++ (GCC) 4.8.5.

The g++ complains that `error: no matches converting function ‘create’ to type ‘using create_t = class Base* (*)() {aka class Base* (*)()}’`. It seams that the sentence `create_t pf = create<S>;` fails, but I have no idea what it is about.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}; 
    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << "In Base." << std::endl;
    }   
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << "In Derived." << std::endl;
    }   
};


template<typename T>
class Factory {
public:
    using create_t = T* (*) (); 

    template<typename S>
    T* create() {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<T, S>::value, "S must be a derived of T.");
        return new S();
    }   

    template<typename S>
    void test() {
        create_t pf = create<S>;
        T * pt = pf();
        pt->print();                                                                                                                                                                                              
        delete pt;
    }   
};

int main() {
    Factory<Base> base_factory;
    base_factory.test<Derived>();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss a `static` keyword:

```
template<typename S>
static T* create() {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<T, S>::value, "S must be a derived of T.");
    return new S();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2622322b4440aa95)

Because without `static`, it's a non-static member function, its type is `T* (Factory::*) ();`
If you really need it as a non-static member function:

```
using self = Factory;
using create_t = T* (self::*) (); 

template<typename S>
T* create() {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<T, S>::value, "S must be a derived of T.");
    return new S();
}   

template<typename S>
void test() {
    create_t pf = &self::create<S>;
    T * pt = (this->*pf)();
    pt->print();                                                                                                                                                                                              
    delete pt;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6af47153c53138c)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. But why a non-static function does not work? It is ok for non-template plain version.